# No transactions when java-configured spring app is running under Wildfly 9

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

We are updating an old Spring application to use java-config instead of XML.
The application runs fine during unit tests, but when deployed under Wildfly it seems that the transactions are inactive and the entity manager is never closed : we don't see inserts/updates being sent to the DB, and despite loggers `org.springframework.transaction` and
`org.springframework.orm.jpa` are set to DEBUG we are not getting traces of transaction begin/end.

We are using Wildfly 9.0.2 with wildfly BOM (=> Hibernate 4.3.10) and Spring 4.3.7.
We have two application modules (.war) and a persistence module (.jar) shared between them.

The persistence module holds the JpaConfig.java and DaoConfig.java configuration classes :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource datasource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(datasource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("my.package.for.entities");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("my-pu");
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setShowSql(LOG.isDebugEnabled());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("java:/appDS");
    }

    protected Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hibernate.dialect", MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class.getName());
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", LOG.isDebugEnabled() ? "true" : "false");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        return props;
    }
}
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.package.for.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class DaoConfig {
 ...
}
```

We've been trying multiple variations of the above (returning LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean directly instead of calling afterPropertiesSet + getObject and returning the EntityManager, with and without a persistence.xml in META-INF, with and without a "Dependencies" manifest entry, being less redundant between Configuration classes, ...), without success.

Both WARs have their own configuration classes, all of which import JpaConfig.java and are annotated with @EnableTransactionManagement, such as :

```
@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, ServicesConfig.class, ControllerConfig.java, JpaConfig.class, DaoConfig.class })
public class RootConfig {
  ...
}
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan("com.my.controller")
public class ControllerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:security.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.my.services")
@Import(DaoConfig.class)
...
}
```

All controllers are annotated with `@Transactional`, so I would expect Spring to create a new transaction whenever an endpoint is called, and flush and close the EM + commit the transaction when the methods return. But this doesn't happen : here is an extract of our logs :

```
INFO  [RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor] [Start call] POST http://server/web/api/rest/catalog/2
INFO  [stdout] Hibernate: select .... from CATALOG catalog0_ where catalog0_.id=?
INFO  [CatalogServiceImpl] Updating catalog #2...
INFO  [CatalogServiceImpl] Catalog #2 updated !
INFO  [RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor] [Call took 23ms] POST http://server/web/api/rest/catalog/2
```

There should be an update statement somewhere.
Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally solved this issue.

Actually, the above configuration is correct. Transactions are properly created. The reason why the changes were not flushed to the DB is that someone (mistakenly) added a `@Immutable` annotation to the entity.

Hibernate doesn't log any warning, and doesn't throw, when an `@Immutable` entity is updated. So in case you are having the same problem... check the annotations on the entity.

In case any Hibernate maintainer finds this answer : it'd be nice that hibernate logs a warning by default when an immutable entity is updated. That would make  it easier to spot such coding errors.